# template style not working for 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, rwd

I want to create responsive email templates and for that I need to add media queries in templates, but whenever I add any style in  of transactional emails, it appears in Preview but doesn't appear in emails.

I have tried adding internal css in html file of email template also but that too is not working.

Is this possible in this version of magento, or is there any way to create responsive templates in 1.9.0.1 version of magento.

I also want to ask that does magento 1.9.0.1 version provide responsiveness in email, may be that's why it isn't working. There is no option to add css file in Configuration -> Design -> Transactional emails.

Please let me know if responsive emails is possible or not in version 1.9.0.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you simply try to flush the cache? It might be that Magento loads old versions of the template.

Furthermore, you should add the stylesheets inline between the body tags, since some clients will strip the head tag completely.

From what I know Magento does not strip anything in the HTML, so I believe if it is not one of the above there should be an error in the template. Have you tested it by sending an e-mail with that HTML directly to your inbox using pure PHP or use a third party service like MailChimp.

Also be aware not all clients [support mediaqueries](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/#mobile-support).

Comment: yes I have flushed magento cache's. And I have tried adding <style>td { background: red !important; }</style> in template, but that too is not working. Not only media queries but simple inline css is also not working.

Comment: Could you share the template code? Or at least the interesting layout part?

Comment: I have created new email template for this:<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; width:650px; margin:auto; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333333;font-size: 13px;" ><style>td {
    background: red !important;
}
</style>
<table><tr><td>Test content</td></tr></table>